# Trying to move a row to another sheet if a date is entered in excel

Tags: excel, vba, row, move

I am using the code below and it's moving the row when I enter non-date entries.  If I enter text, it moves the row.  I only want it to move if there is a date in it.  It doesn't matter what date, but it has to be a date.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Value > Date - 10000 Then
            With Target.EntireRow
                .Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                .Delete
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `IsDate` to check. Also use `Target.Cells.CountLarge` instead of `Target.Cells.Count`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some improvements to your code:

1. Even though you could do it in just one line, I added the multiple `IFs` and `Exit Sub` if conditions are not met (just makes code more readable IMO)
2. Use objects to manipulate data when possible, for example, set a reference to the target sheet and reuse it in your code
3. Full qualify the objects (for example, `Rows.Count` should be `targetSheet.Rows.Count`)

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    ' Check if is in column "B" and just one cell
    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then Exit Sub

    ' Check if is date
    If IsDate(Target.Value) = False Then Exit Sub

    ' Check if is greater than current date - 10000 days
    If Target.Value <= (Date - 10000) Then Exit Sub

    ' Copy and delete row
    With Target.EntireRow
        ' Use full qualifying of objects (for example, Rows.Count should be targetSheet.Rows.Count)
        .Copy targetSheet.Range("A" & targetSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works